# username and password for importing Oracle .dmp file

Tags: oracle

Need to import an Oracle .dmp file, and wondering if there is a way to skip original username and password for the source Oracle database when we export the .dmp file? I have sys/system permission on the destination Oracle database.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the impdp utility you can import using the system user. Specify remap_schema and remap_tablespace to import your tables into a different schema and tablespace.

```
impdp system/password@database dumpfile=dump.dmp directory=directory remap_schema=from:to remap_tablespace=from:to
```

Oracle documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm

Comment: Thanks @Rene, wondering if I can skip parameter of remap_schema and remap_tablespace? I just need to import the data once, and export to csv/txt file from the imported dmp file later. Your advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: BTW, Rene, for "system/password@database", it is password for source database where dmp is exported, or password for destination database where import to? Thanks.

Comment: Destination. Once you have the dumpfile you have nothing to do with the source database anymore.

Comment: Thanks Rene, and what means @database? Shall I change "database" to something else? :)

Comment: It's the connect string for your destination database.

Comment: Thanks Rene, do you know if there is a GUI import option for .dmp file from SQL developer?